# How to decrease vertical whitespace before and after an equation

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical-alignment

I want to decrease the vertical space before and after an equation. But the effect should not be global! So I just want to change a the vertical space of a part of my equations.

Here is an example of my problem:

```
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\begin{table}[H]
   \centering

   \begin{footnotesize}  
   \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{6.5cm}}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Gleichung} \\
      \midrule
      \midrule
      Text T &
      \begin{equation}
         T(x_t) =
         \begin{cases}
            1 & x_t \leq 1 \\
            2 & x_t \leq 2 \\
            3 & x_t \leq 3 \\
            4 & sonst
         \end{cases}
      \label{eq:equation}
      \end{equation} \\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \end{footnotesize}

   \caption{caption}
   \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
```

So I have a table with 2 columns and n rows. In the right column I want to place equations in each row with zero spacing before and after the equation.

At the moment the `\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}` seems to have no effect.

Can anyone help me?

Greetings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you provide a full code with the document class and the package used?

Comment: Sorry. I use a template class that I didnt wrote by myself with tons of included packages. I just search maybe a simple hack for now.

Comment: a quick may be the use of `\vspace{-1em}`, you can change the 1 for another value of course

Comment: Yep, perfect. I already use this at the moment. But where, in which cls file, can I find the default values for `\belowdisplayskip`, so that I can adjust the space correctly?

Comment: This is a grosspost to [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,77458.html#77458).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an additional `minipage` surrounding the equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
   \footnotesize
   \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{6.5cm}}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Gleichung} \\
      \midrule
      \midrule
      Text T &
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \begin{equation}
         T(x_t) =
         \begin{cases}
            1 & x_t \leq 1 \\
            2 & x_t \leq 2 \\
            3 & x_t \leq 3 \\
            4 & sonst
         \end{cases}
      \label{eq:equation}
      \end{equation}
      \end{minipage} \\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{caption}
   \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To flush the equation to the left, one may use

```
$\begin{aligned}[t]
        T(x_t) =
         \begin{cases}
            1 & x_t \leq 1 \\
            2 & x_t \leq 2 \\
            3 & x_t \leq 3 \\
            4 & sonst
         \end{cases}
      \end{aligned}\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)$
```

In this case no `minipage`s are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
   \footnotesize
   \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{6.5cm}}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Gleichung} \\
      \midrule
      \midrule
      Text T &
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
        T(x_t) =
         \begin{cases}
            1 & x_t \leq 1 \\
            2 & x_t \leq 2 \\
            3 & x_t \leq 3 \\
            4 & sonst
         \end{cases}
      \end{aligned}\hfill \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)$\\
      \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{caption}
   \label{tab:table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very very much. Simple, fast solution and exactly what I wanted to do :).

Comment: There is no need of setting the spacing parameters. Try without those settings and you'll see.

Comment: @egreg: With `minipage`, yes. I will change the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Is there a posibility to align the equation in the minipages horizontally? So can I align the text in a minipage to the left?

Comment: @SteveMurdock: One option is to use `fleqn` option to `amsmath`. But this will affect all equations.

Comment: @SteveMurdock Like that? See the update.

Comment: E x c e l l e n t :). No more words. Thank you very much, "again"!